# LWC Component with Different Context based on Record Page v Home Page

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a component that is just filling out a lightning-datatable. When opened on a record page, it fills with data specific to that record. This is working as expected. But I would also like to have it fill with all currently active data created by the current user (not record-specific) if it is opened on a home page.

Here is what I am using for when the recordId exists:

```
    @wire(getList,{accId:'$recordId'})
    list(result){
        morestuff;
    }
```

But when the recordId is undefined, the getList method never runs. Is there a way to easily go about this? Basically the getList function just has a different SOQL query returned based on whether the recordId exists or not. But the function never runs if it doesn't exist (understandable, per the important note in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_record_context))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a getter/setter to insert a null value:

```
_recordId;
@api set recordId(value) {
  this._recordId = value || null;
}
get recordId() {
  return this._recordId;
}
```

`_recordId` is just a notation I use for backing/internal variables, you can name it whatever you like. You might need to adjust your wire method to for reactivity to work, as the documentation isn't clear on that.

Comment: Much more elegant than the workaround I had come up with! I just had to change the "= value || null" part because that seemed to accept undefined as a value and it never came out as null.